# How to use ES Java API to create a new type of an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have succeed create an index use Client , the code like this :

```
public static boolean addIndex(Client client,String index) throws Exception {
    if(client == null){
        client = getSettingClient();
    }
    CreateIndexRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(index);
    CreateIndexResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
    return response.isAcknowledged();  
    //client.close();
}

public static boolean addIndexType(Client client, String index, String type) throws Exception {
    if (client == null) {
        client = getSettingClient();
    }
    TypesExistsAction action = TypesExistsAction.INSTANCE;
    TypesExistsRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new TypesExistsRequestBuilder(client, action, index);
    requestBuilder.setTypes(type);
    TypesExistsResponse response = requestBuilder.get();
    return response.isExists();
}
```

however, the method of addIndexType is not effected, the type is not create .

I don't know how to create type ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create types when you create the index by providing a proper mapping configuration. Alternatively a type gets created when you index a document of a certain type. However the first suggestion is the better one, because then you can control the full mapping of that type instead of relying on dynamic mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can set types in the following way:

```
// JSON schema is the JSON mapping which you want to give for the index.

JSONObject builder = new JSONObject().put(type, JSONSchema);

// And then just fire the below command

client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName)
                        .setType(type)
                        .setSource(builder.toString(), XContentType.JSON)
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();
```